# iterate over nested hash and modify values in place

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to 'monkey patch' some code we have deployed without breaking the API consumer, basically I want to find param with a key value pair, with value equaling certain value('\u0000') and set it to nil, here is what I have :

```
def traverse_param(key, value)
  if value.is_a? Hash
    value.each do |k, v|
      return traverse_param(k, v)
    end
  end
  if value == '\u0000'
     value = nil
  end
end
```

In rails 5 I cannot pass `nil` to the controller as it will be cast to `''` and I need to pass the `nil` in param onto the service doing the work below.

Now since I can have nested params this is why I check if the param value is a `Hash`. I worked with this example :

```
params = {:filters=>{:user=>{:disabled_at=>"\u0000"}, :importan_param=>1}}
params.each { |k, v| traverse_param(k,v)  }
```

I m trying to modify the value in place, but it does not seem to work? The code is entering the right places when I debug, but it's not producing desired outcome. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). It sounds like the problem you're trying to solve is that you're getting `\u0000` in your params where you don't want it, but the question you've asked is instead about how to implement a specific solution, which may or may not be the correct solution. I suggest expanding your question to describe the actual problem you have.

Comment: Hi @JordanRunning the problem is that before I upgrade rails 5, I was able to pass in nil in my filters. Which I was able to pass down my filtering service, which would generate `is null` query. But now after the upgrade to rails5, when I send `nil` from client, blank `''` arrives at the back-end and the service below is producing wrong query which compares some column to `''` which is not the same thing. So I m trying to have this 'special' case when they pass it, it will produce `is null` query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem you're facing is that you're modifying a local variable `value`. Were you to pass the entire params hash (or sub-hash) to `traverse`, you can then update the values as so:

```
def traverse(params)
  params.each do |k, v|
    traverse(v) if v.is_a? Hash        
    params[k] = nil if v == '\u0000'
  end
end

# => {:filters=>{:user=>{:disabled_at=>nil}, :importan_param=>1}}
```

You can tidy this a little using [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) if you're Ruby > 2.4:

```
def traverse(params)
  params.dup.transform_values { |v| v == "\\u0000" ? nil : v.is_a?(Hash) ? traverse(v) : v }
end

traverse(params)
# => {:filters=>{:user=>{:disabled_at=>nil}, :importan_param=>1}}
params
# => {:filters=>{:user=>{:disabled_at=>"\\u0000"}, :importan_param=>1}}
```

Or, far more readable:

```
def traverse(params)
  params.dup.transform_values do |v| 
    next traverse(v) if v.is_a?(Hash)
    v == "\\u0000" ? nil : v
  end
end
```

Hope that's useful - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @SRack I like both of your solutions, ideally I'd like to keep the original params unmodified. I also tried second solution, it does not modify the hash, the first one works. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the `!` from `transform_values` - I've updated the second solution now. Have also updated so your original params are preserved, while this returns the updated hash (as you want it). If you do want to modify the existing hash, remove the `dup`. Hopefully that does it for you @Remember_me :)

Comment: @Remember_me - I've updated again, the last iteration was also removing the param you wanted to keep. Would recommend using the third, readable version.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using `params.dup.transform_values!` instead of `params.transform_values` (no `!`)? The point of `transform_values!` is to modify the original object, but `dup` makes a copy of the object so the original isn't modified.

Comment: It _was_ for the recursive call to the method @JordanRunning. One of the previous iterations required it, though I've just tested it out and it seems this is no longer the case (thought it was still necessary). Thanks for the note - I've updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing `each` for mapping. Mapping is to be done with `map`, `each` is for *iterating*.

```
def fix(hash)
  hash.map do |k, v|
    [k, case v
        when Hash then fix(v)
        when '\u0000' then nil
        else v
        end]
  end.to_h
end
```